# Using Cordova iOS 4 with iOS older than 8.0

Tags: ios, cordova

Has anyone tried upgrading to the Cordova iOS >= 4.0.0 and use the app with iOS 7 or 6?
According to [Cordova 4.0.0 documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/12/08/cordova-ios-4.0.0.html):

> The minimum deployment target has been updated to iOS 8.0. This means that this platform release has only been tested on iOS 8 devices and greater only and will only support those iOS versions.

Since some of our app users are still working with iOS 6 & 7 we wonder how safe it is upgrading to Cordova iOS 4+

Thanks!

Comment: Best thing you can do is try it yourself. Everything should work on iOS 7, but I'm not so sure about iOS 6

Comment: From my experience with upgrading Cordova - Updating the app to Cordova iOS 4 is far from being a simple task. Before spending hours on it I try to learn from other's experience if it worked out for them with iOS 6,7 :-)

Comment: If you do things correctly, you just have to remove ios platform and and ios 4 platform, if something doesn't work just remove the ios platform again and add 3.9.2. But 3.9.2 wasn't compatible with iOS 6 neither.

Comment: Once there are complex dependencies and multiple plugins adding and removing a platform can be a real headache (lot's of experience with that...). But thanks for the reply anyway